# Laravel insert array to DB and associate another array with it's id's

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am looping through an array and generate 3 arrays. One that goes to Event table, one for address table and another for geoloc table. Problem is that geoloc + address table needs event_id which is a foreign key linked to id in event table.  I am doing a bulk insert because there are a lot of records in the array, roughly about 1500. Is it possible to associate address and geoloc with event id when `$event` is a bulk insert?

```
foreach ($facebookEvents as $facebookEvent) {
    if (!empty($facebookEvent['event_times'][0]['start_time'])) {
        foreach ($facebookEvent['event_times'] as $recurrence) {
            $eventsArray[] = [
                'type' => 'Facebook Event',
                'startdate' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($recurrence['start_time'])),
                'endate' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($recurrence['end_time'])),
                'startime' => date('H:i:s', strtotime($facebookEvent['start_time'])),
                'endtime' => date('H:i:s', strtotime($facebookEvent['end_time'])),
                'title' => $facebookEvent['name'],
                'description' => $facebookEvent['description'],
                'entity_id' => $event,
            ];
            $addressArray[] = [
                'town' => $facebookEvent['place']['location']['city'],
                'address' => $facebookEvent['place']['location']['street'],
                'postcode' => $facebookEvent['place']['location']['zip'],
                            // also event id from each $eventsarray
            ];
            $geolocArray[] = [
                'lat' => $facebookEvent['place']['location']['latitude'],
                'lng' => $facebookEvent['place']['location']['longitude'],
                            // also event id from each $eventsarray saved
            ];
        }
    } 
}
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
    $env = config('app.name');
    $command = 'Facebook Recalculate';
    Notification::route('slack', 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/T30BGA1EW/B7A9TEC3F/N0FqRyzdsdsdsDN5SVxiN')
    ->notify(new JobErrorNotification($error, $env, $command));
}
}
$event = Event::insert($eventsArray);
    //save address array and add $event->id for each one
    // same for geoloc
$algolia = Event::all()->searchable();
}
```